# jquery does not attach click to all h1 tags in my debugger

Tags: jquery

I have made a debugger for the websites i develop that i simply include at the bottom of the page. Now because i include it after the  tag, it might cause some problems i know but so far i haven't seen any but this:

http://www.abitnerdy.se/tmp/debuggertest

click to open the debugger, and then click on for example the dbquery part. What i notice is that it sometimes not opens, and sometimes it does. Exactly like the application log. Can't quite understand why it is doing that.
I have attached an alert to see what div is going to be shown, and then i came to the conclusion that the click didn't attach.

The problem somehow only seems to occur at the last 2 divs.

anyone any idea's where to look?

by the way, feel free to use the code if you think it is usefull for your own projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the last 2 h1 (`<h1 id="dbquery" class="debug">`) has same ID attribute and inside your click function you have something like `if(current != $(this).attr("id"))` So If one of the last 2 h1 is open it will not allow the other one to open.

**Edit:** I quickly changed the last h1 to a different ID in Firebug and then it worked fine for me.. So change the ID of one of last 2 h1 and It should work fine.

Comment: jeezus, that is a beginners error ;) Sorry about that. I guess i have stared myself blind on other things but that.

Answer (score 0):

Your last two items both have `id="dbquery"`.  That will definitely cause problems.  Change the id on your last one.

The duplicate means that when either of the last two is open, you can't click on the other one because your code thinks the viewer is clicking on the one that's already open and therefore does nothing.  If you give the last one to `id="dblog"` or something like that, it should start working.

FYI:

`$(this).attr("id")` is quite inefficient (two function calls, the creation of a jQuery object and several internal lookups) when `this.id` works just fine (a straight property reference).  Folks should only use jQuery when it is actually more efficient to type or execute, not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It's look like problem is due to last two h1 having same id